# Issue with Stack Navigator when building apk using App center

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

FAIL **tests**/App-test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

```
/Users/runner/runners/2.168.2/work/1/s/node_modules/@react-navigation/stack/lib/commonjs/views/assets/back-icon.png:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){�PNG


SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

  at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:537:17)
  at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:579:25)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@react-navigation/stack/lib/commonjs/index.tsx:13:3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution that worked for me:

You have to do install `npm install --save-dev identity-obj-proxy` (or `yarn add identity-obj-proxy`) to get the necessary dependencies.

```
  "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      ".+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    }
  }
```

Source: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2663#issuecomment-341384494